# Find nearest point horizontal in imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to find the nearest point to the point (red in this case) in this image. In this image this output find the first line point from right

how I could do this

[image]

output

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Do You know the coordinates of the red point? Do You know the "background" and "line" colors exactly?

Comment: yes i know the coordinates of red point

Comment: i know the line color

Comment: the background is white

Comment: What programming language do You need to use? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: i use imagemagick

Comment: But any language would work well

Comment: Imagemagick is not a programming tool, it is an image manipulation program. What is desired output? The x coordinate of the nearest line as a number?

Comment: the cordinates of the point of nearest line

Comment: only need the coordinates of the nearest point to point red I enclose in a blue circle

Comment: If You knew the equations representing the lines and point's coordinates, You would only need some maths. If You do not know the equations, You can try to find the line going pixel by pixel from the point to the "left", until You encounter pixel of the line color.

Comment: Do You know the lines equations? Or is Your input the bitmap image?

Comment: is a bitmap image i dont know the equation only know the cordinates of red point and the colors of image

Comment: Ok, then: First, load the image to the memory. How to do this depends on what programming tool You are using - in PHP You can use imagemagick or gd extensions, in other languages there are other libraries to load and handle bitmap images.

Comment: Then, when You have the image in memory, initialize the `x` and `y` coordinates of the red point. The try decrementing the `x` coordinate, read bitmap color at `[x, y]` and check if it has the line color or not. If it does, You have Your result in `x`. If it does not, continue decrementing `x` and testing.

Answer (score 1):

This looks fun! Let's dump the image to text using **ImageMagick**:

```
convert image.png txt: 

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 337,218,65535,srgb
0,0: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  white
1,0: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  white
2,0: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  white
3,0: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  white
4,0: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  white
...
...
221,79: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
221,80: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
221,81: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
221,82: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
...
...
```

Ok, now let's use `awk` to find all black pixels and print their (x,y) coordinates:

```
convert image.png txt: | awk -F'[,:]' '/black/{x=$1;y=$2;print x,y}'

221 79
221 80
221 81
221 82
221 83
221 84
...
...
```

Ok, now let's tell `awk` where the red pixel is by passing in `rx` (red x-coordinate) and `ry` (red y-coordinate). Then also, calculate the sum of the squares of the x-distance and y-distance from red to each black pixel. When it is less (i.e. nearer) than any seen so far, save the location. Print the nearest location at the end.

```
convert image.png txt: | awk -F'[,:]' -v rx=318 -v ry=127 '
   BEGIN{m=999999}
   /black/{
            x=$1; y=$2; d2=(rx-x)*(rx-x)+(ry-y)*(ry-y)
            if(d2<m){m=d2;xm=x;ym=y}
   }
   END{print xm,ym}'

277 127
```

So, that is the answer... (277,127). Let's check it by drawing a cyan circle there:

```
convert image.png -fill cyan -draw "circle 277,127 277,132" check.png
```

[image]

---

On re-reading the question, I note that you actually only want the horizontally closest point whereas my solution above caters for the general case in any direction. If you just want horizontal offset, and you know the horizontal line is at y-coordinate 127, you can just extract that specific row from the image and simplify things like this:

```
convert image.png -crop x1+0+127 txt: | awk -F'[,:]' -v rx=318 '
   BEGIN{m=999999} /black/{x=$1;d=(rx-x)*(rx-x);if(d<m){m=d;xm=x}} END{print xm}'
277
```

If you don't like `awk`, you can just do it by eyeball...

```
convert image.png -crop x1+0+127 txt: | grep -E "black|red"

221,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
277,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black         <--- nearest black to red
314,0: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
315,0: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
316,0: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
317,0: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
318,0: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
319,0: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
320,0: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
```

---

How did I find the coordinates of the red pixel? I used **ImageMagick**'s sub-image search looking for a red pixel like this:

```
compare -metric rmse -subimage-search -dissimilarity-threshold 1 image.png \( -size 1x1 xc:red \) null:

0 (0) @ 317,121
```

---

**Notes**:

I just used the sum of the squares rather than the square root of the sum of the squares because it is computationally faster and the results are the same because it holds that if a>b, then a * a > b * b in this case.

I used slightly different `rx` and `ry` from those generated by the sub-image search because OP says he had the coordinates and the ones found by sub-image search don't find the exact centre of the rather large red blob, but instead the top-leftmost edge of the red blob.